# I can't able to remove and redraw the graph in react highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, next.js

Simple problem,
I can't able to remove and redraw the chart.
I have not found any solution for react highchart.

here is my code

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const chartComponent = useRef(null);
  const [options] = useState({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "chart",
      type: "spline",
      zoomType: "x",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      plotBorderColor: "transparent"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Chart"
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      tickPixelInterval: 200,
      gridLineColor: "red",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "red"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "red",
      minorGridLineColor: "red",
      tickColor: "red",
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      gridLineColor: "red",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "red"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "red",
      minorGridLineColor: "red",
      tickColor: "red"
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: "Random Number"
      }
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      if (chartComponent.current) {
        chartComponent.current.chart.series[0].addPoint(
          [new Date().getTime(), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)],
          true
        );
      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  function clearChart() {
    if (chartComponent.current) {
      chartComponent.current.chart.series[0].remove(false);
      chartComponent.current.chart.redraw();
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HighchartsReact
        ref={chartComponent}
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
      />
      <center>
        <button onClick={clearChart}>Clear Chart</button>
      </center>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am using this code for redraw the graph -

```
function clearChart() {
    if (chartComponent.current) {
      chartComponent.current.chart.series[0].remove(false);
      chartComponent.current.chart.redraw();
    }
  }
```

But **redraw** function is not redrawing the graph, hence I am getting error. because loop still try to push value in not existing graph.
here is the codesandbox project https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-fire-lms4nq

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval in each `clearChart` function call. You can do that as below:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  const chartComponent = useRef(null);
  const [hasSeries, setHasSeries] = useState(true);
  const [options] = useState({...});

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      if (hasSeries && chartComponent.current) {
        chartComponent.current.chart.series[0].addPoint(
          [new Date().getTime(), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)],
          true
        );
      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [hasSeries, chartComponent]);

  function clearChart() {
    if (chartComponent.current) {
      setHasSeries(false);
      chartComponent.current.chart.series[0].remove(false);
      chartComponent.current.chart.redraw();
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HighchartsReact
        ref={chartComponent}
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
      />
      <center>
        <button onClick={clearChart}>Clear Chart</button>
      </center>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-blackwell-p3k31-p3k31y?file=/pages/index.js

Useful article: https://www.codementor.io/@damianpereira/how-to-use-clearinterval-inside-react-s-useeffect-and-why-it-is-important-1si7mztjlk

Comment: It's just stoped drawing chart. But I want it to clear the chart, not stopping the loop. Loop should continuously draw... After i clear the chart, it should immediately start drawing the chart as like it's initialised now

Comment: Hi @Munny Reol, Thanks for the more detailed description of the problem. In this case, you just need to call `series.setData([])` instead of `series.remove()`. Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-for-m9kj13?file=/demo.jsx